# What's an easy way to edit 256+ color toolbar resources in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resources, visual-c++, toolbar

When I go to edit a toolbar resource in VS2008, it converts it to a 16color (4-bit) bitmap.  WTF?  What do you use to edit toolbars that doesn't suck?

You've got to be kidding me... surely there is an add-on or a plug-in to the VS2008 resource editor to make it work correctly with high color bitmaps?  This just seems insane.  How are all of those many apps out there producing a toolbar without a reasonable toolbar editor available to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use icofx from [here](http://icofx.ro/).

Comment: Am I to understand that you're saving every toolbar icon as an independent .ico file, and then assembling an image list (or equivalent) at runtime?

Comment: No, you can create a big toolbar image and put in a series of icons into it and then assemble it into an image-list at runtime, make sure the icons are of a consistent size to ensure it can be loaded. Have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/AlphaImageImagelist.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use [Axialis IconWorkshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/), but I don't know whether it can edit toolbar resources.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you don't use MSPaint ?

Practical answer - at least in the MFc days, no you had to edit it separately.
Today I would probably use paint.net

Comment: I thought MS used it to design the visual style of Windows